# Div style in css, how to start under then button

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have red div of the right site and button on the left
Now test start under the red div, but I want to that text start under the button and then under the red div.
Here is current not working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/QdvFp/127/

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child2">Button</div>
</div>
<div>
    My text, which should start on the left site under the buttton, and then go under the red div, like in newspapers
</div>

.child{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* for IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* for IE7*/
    margin-right:10px;
    background:red;
    min-width:100px;
    min-height:50px;

}
.parent{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.child2{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* for IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* for IE7*/
        background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `float: left` to `.child` class:

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  /* for IE7*/
  *zoom: 1;
  /* for IE7*/
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: red;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.child2 {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  /* for IE7*/
  *zoom: 1;
  /* for IE7*/
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child2">Button</div>
</div>
<div>
  My text, which should start on the left site under the buttton, and then go under the red div, like in newspapers
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `float:left;`

```
.child{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* for IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* for IE7*/
    margin-right:10px;
    background:red;
    min-width:100px;
    min-height:50px;
    float: left; /*add this css rule*/
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QdvFp/128/)